# angular2-rc4 http.post not working for chrome and IE

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've written one service to perform http post operation in @angular2-rc1. After updating to rc4, its stopped working in chrome and ie although its working in firefox.
When i try to send data through post request, its showing data in firebug(inspect element of chrome) in request, but server is getting empty string. 
Below is the code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, BaseRequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    login(url:string, data: string) {
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this.http.post(url, data, options);
    }

}
```

Code used to invoke this login method is:

```
this._httpService.login('rest/j_spring_security_check', 'j_username=user&j_password=pass').subscribe(
                data => this.authenticationSuccess(data),
                error => this.authenticationFailure(error)
            )
```

When i try to login through firefox, server is getting username and password properly, whereas server is getting empty string if same is done through chrome or ie.
Please help.

Comment: Solution is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390605/angular2-rc4-text-plain-is-automatically-getting-appended-in-content-type-when

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `FormData` object directly like this with RC4:

```
login(url:string, data: string) {
  var body = new FormData();
  body.append('j_username', data.user);
  body.append('j_password', data.pass);

  return this.http.post(url, body);
}
```

or the URLSearchParams class:

```
login(url:string, data: string) {
  var body = new URLSearchParams();
  body.set('j_username', data.user);
  body.set('j_password', data.pass);

  return this.http.post(url, body);
}
```

and call the `login` method this way:

```
httpService.login('rest/j_spring_security_check', {
  user: 'user', pass: 'pass').subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I'm using spring security for authentication which mandates to pass request data in this format: j_username=user&j_password=pass in a single line. If I'll send data in json format, spring security will not be able to read it.